# How to fix a calculate value tool to work in a large model and skip featureless rasters?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I'm attempting to run a model that contains some rasters that do not have any features after being processed through my raster calculator. I have a calculate value tool from a [previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168776/using-calculate-value-tool-in-modelbuilder-to-ignore-skip-rasters-without-featur/168790#168790) that works exactly as it is shown. The issue is that tool doesn't work when placed within the model. I changed the Data Type to Variant and the calculate value tool runs but returns this error: [image]

The point of the calculate tool was to find these "bad" rasters and skip over them. The calculate value tool correctly identifies and skips rasters in a less complicated model.

Here is the calculate value: [image]

Does anyone know how I can make this calculate value tool work in my big model?

I'm more than open to changing the calculate value code block to run a different process if using Getproperties is causing the issue.

Comment: The Data Type must be Boolean.

Comment: @Hornbydd I ran it as a Boolean and still produced the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to tweak the code to do a find and replace, below is the updated code. This code assume that it will always find a \ symbol.

```py
import arcpy,string
def CheckRaster(r):
  #r will have \ so we need to replace them with /
  r = string.replace(r,'\\','/')
  result = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(r, "MINIMUM")
  n = int(result.getOutput(0))
  if n > 1:
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

Comment: This fixed the forward slash issue. Unfortunately it still does not identify the rasters without features. It gives the same error as above.

Comment: Well you are specifically testing if it's minimum value is greater than one, so to answer that you need to have statistics built. So you need to add a step into your model that calls the tool to build statistics for %Raster_03%.